# If selected option value is empty select all values in column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get all values from column when color selected option value is empty. 
I have created form, and dropdown menu looks like

Colors

```
<option value="">
<option value="61">8019 - Smeđa
<option value="28">8017 - Smedja svijetla
<option value="27">8004 - Cigla crvena
<option value="26">8003 - Boja bakra
```

dimensions

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dimensions))
{
echo '<option value= "'.$row['ArtOpis'].'">'.$row['ArtOpis'].'</option>'; 
}

?>
</select>
```

If I achoose dimension and leave color values empty, then all colors from selected menu should be printed. For ex. if a want srew 4,4x20 mm dimension, if I dont choose color, leave it blank, I want to print this screw in all colors. 
    vijci_search2.php

```
$col=$_POST['color']

$dimen=$_POST['dimensions'];
$sql_color = (!empty($col)) ? "jos_ib_boje.BojaId=" . $col . " AND " : '';


Query
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT jos_ib_artikli.ArtSifra, jos_ib_artikli.ArtNaziv, jos_ib_artikli.ArtOpis,jos_ib_artikli.ArtKategorija, jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja, jos_ib_jedmj.JmNaziv, jos_ib_pakovanja.PakOznaka, 
jos_ib_artikli.ArtStanjeSa, jos_ib_artikli.ArtStanjeBL, jos_ib_boje.BojaId, jos_ib_boje.BojaNaziv

FROM jos_ib_artikli

INNER JOIN jos_ib_jedmj ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtMjera = jos_ib_jedmj.JmId

INNER JOIN jos_ib_pakovanja ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtPakovanje = jos_ib_pakovanja.PakId

INNER JOIN jos_ib_boje ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja = jos_ib_boje.BojaId

WHERE jos_ib_artikli.ArtOpis LIKE '$dimen' AND jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja='$sql_color' AND jos_ib_artikli.ArtStanjeSa>0");
```

Comment: What is the problem? what you want to achieve is not clear.

Comment: I have two selections. First is to select dimension and second to select color. When I select screw dimension for ex 5x5 mm, and hit search I want to display screws with 5,5 dimension with all colors not just specific color. The key here is when color value is left blank with no value to print all values from column.

Comment: You could do an ajax call when a dimension is selected and request all the colors for that dimension and then populate the color-select with the (JSON) result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. 
The mistake was here.
//bad
$sql_color = (!empty($col)) ? "jos_ib_boje.BojaId=" . $col . " AND " : '';

//good
$sql_color = (!empty($col)) ? " AND jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja=" . $color . "  " : '';

$sql = "SELECT jos_ib_artikli.ArtSifra, jos_ib_artikli.ArtNaziv, jos_ib_artikli.ArtOpis,jos_ib_artikli.ArtKategorija, jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja, jos_ib_jedmj.JmNaziv, jos_ib_pakovanja.PakOznaka, 
    jos_ib_artikli.ArtStanjeSa, jos_ib_artikli.ArtStanjeBL, jos_ib_boje.BojaId, jos_ib_boje.BojaNaziv

```
FROM jos_ib_artikli

INNER JOIN jos_ib_jedmj ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtMjera = jos_ib_jedmj.JmId

INNER JOIN jos_ib_pakovanja ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtPakovanje = jos_ib_pakovanja.PakId

INNER JOIN jos_ib_boje ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja = jos_ib_boje.BojaId

WHERE jos_ib_artikli.ArtOpis LIKE '$dimenzija'  ". $sql_bojalica . "  AND ArtStanjeSA>0 " ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$col=$_POST['color']

$dimen=$_POST['dimensions'];

$query .= "SELECT jos_ib_artikli.ArtSifra, jos_ib_artikli.ArtNaziv, jos_ib_artikli.ArtOpis,jos_ib_artikli.ArtKategorija, jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja, jos_ib_jedmj.JmNaziv, jos_ib_pakovanja.PakOznaka, 
jos_ib_artikli.ArtStanjeSa, jos_ib_artikli.ArtStanjeBL, jos_ib_boje.BojaId, jos_ib_boje.BojaNaziv

FROM jos_ib_artikli

INNER JOIN jos_ib_jedmj ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtMjera = jos_ib_jedmj.JmId

INNER JOIN jos_ib_pakovanja ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtPakovanje = jos_ib_pakovanja.PakId

INNER JOIN jos_ib_boje ON jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja = jos_ib_boje.BojaId

WHERE jos_ib_artikli.ArtOpis LIKE '$dimen'";

if($col != '' && !empty($col)) { $query .= " AND jos_ib_boje.BojaId=" . $col ."";}

$query .= " AND jos_ib_artikli.ArtBoja='$sql_color' AND jos_ib_artikli.ArtStanjeSa>0";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

what about this variable ($sql_color) its not defined so first defined it and then run query??